# Dash dropdown not showing values

Tags: python, web-applications, drop-down-menu, plotly-dash, pythonanywhere

I have a Python web app built with Dash in a Pythonanywhere server. It is working fine in my local machine, but with the same code
in Python Anywhere there is a dropdown menu that is not showing the options...or showing blank values.

I've tried hard coding some values in the options dropdown variable, but nothing appears.

The code is like this:

```
dcc.Dropdown(
id="dd_units",
options=['SORXC01', 'ENDE01'],
value="SORXC01",
searchable=False,),
```

Very simple, so I assume it should be fine.

A sample of what I see on Python Anywhere:

[image: Dropdown issue]

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the dash version installed in Python Anywhere...

```
pip install --upgrade dash
```

And now it is working :)

Answer (score 0):

How are you encapsulating the `dcc.Dropdown` inside a `html` element?

For example:

```
html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id="dd_units",
        options=['SORXC01', 'ENDE01'],
        value="SORXC01",
        searchable=False  # Take care with the comma you have
    ),
])
```

[More info](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/dropdown)

Comment: I have tried but it doesn't work, in fact my original code looks like this. I don't know if could be a Python Anywhere problem...

Comment: I have tried with the sample dropdown provided by dash and it is not working too...